# Joomla 4 not unzipping custom component update package

Tags: joomla-4.x, custom-component, xml, mvc

I have developed a custom Joomla 4 component called "com_news" and successfully implemented the update functionality before. However, now I am encountering an issue where Joomla can't unzip the update package when trying to update the component.

The update server URL and Download ID are recognized, but when the update process starts, Joomla fails to unzip the package and proceeds with the update. I'm not sure what might be causing this issue, as it has worked previously.

Are there any known bugs, limitations, or requirements related to the update package or the update process in Joomla 4 that could be causing this issue? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

### news.xml

```
<updateservers>
    <server type="extension" priority="1" name="News updater">https://github.com/{USER}/{REPO}/raw/master/{UPDATES}.xml</server>
</updateservers>
<dlid prefix="dlid="/>
```

### news_updates.xml

```
<updates>
    <update>
        <name>News Component</name>
        <description>News component installation</description>
        <element>com_news</element>
        <type>component</type>
        <version>1.6.7.2</version>
        <downloads>
            <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">
                https://github.com/{USER}/{REPO}/raw/master/Builds/com_news-v1.6.7.1.zip
                <sha256>{Sha256}</sha256>
            </downloadurl>
        </downloads>
        <maintainer>DeesreX</maintainer>
        <maintainerurl>https://yourwebsite.com</maintainerurl>
        <targetplatform name="joomla" version="4" />
        <tags>
            <tag>stable</tag>
        </tags>
    </update>
    <changelog>https://github.com/{USER}/{REPO}/raw/master/CHANGELOG.md</changelog>
</updates>
```

### Error Code

```
Failed to extract file: com_news-v1.6.7.1.zip_dlid_2374
```